# Axioms of Affine Space

Tags: linear-algebra, axioms, affine-geometry

In every definition of an affine space I see, the affine space is defined as a set $A$ with an associated vector space $V$ with a group action of $V$ on $A$.

But I also see that vector spaces are often identified as "affine spaces with an origin".

This makes me think (/hope) that we there should be some equivalent definition of an affine space that doesn't rely on the concept of a vector space.  Are there some axioms of an $n$-dimensional affine space (analogous to the ones for a vector space) that make no reference to vector spaces?  If so, would we then be able to show that an affine space equipped with an origin satisfies all of the vector space axioms?

Comment: Are you sure that vector spaces can be identified as "affine spaces with an origin" ?  I believe that affine spaces do have an origin, while vector spaces do not. And no, I don't recall seeing affine spaces defined without reference to a vector space.

Comment: Formulating the "affine addition" gets somewhat horrific without the nice tool of a group action ...

Comment: @lmsteffan I think you're confused.  Vector spaces have a zero vector *by definition* which if we're viewing the space geometrically we can call the "origin".  Affine spaces don't naturally have this which means there's no natural way of adding two arbitrary members of the affine space.

Comment: @user287393 Indeed. I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, one can define an affine space over a ground field $\Bbb F$ to be a nonempty set $\Bbb A$ endowed with maps $$\mu: \Bbb A \times \Bbb A \times \Bbb A \to \Bbb A$$ and $$\Lambda: \Bbb F \times \Bbb A \times \Bbb A \to \Bbb A$$ that together satisfy a [particular list of reasonable axioms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+space#two_ternary_operations). Informally, we should think of these maps as $$(x, y, z) \mapsto x - y + z$$ and $$(r, x, y) \mapsto x - rx + ry, $$ so that the former encodes "sums relative to a temporarily fixed basepoint" and the latter "scalar multiplication relative to a temporarily fixed basepoint".

There are numerous definitions of affine spaces, [many of which are recorded at the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+space#summary), including others that make no reference to vector spaces.

Comment: Cool.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it helpful.